# FCC certification process for Part 15

Tags: fcc

I want to take FCC  certification for my product which comes under "Part 15" (Unintentional Product). **What tests are necessary for that?**

Please suggest me some document so that I can refer it and take care of passing test on first attempt.

Comment: Since your product is unintentional, just forget the whole thing.  It's a lot cheaper to abort product development now than after testing.

Comment: You're going to need a test house, which will come with a competent(?) test engineer.

Comment: Had a pretty good chuckle at "unintentional product".

Answer (score 1):

Go read Part 15 to learn more.  Here is a video that will give you a very small taste of what is tested and how you can do some rudimentary testing yourself (maybe) [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLIr1eFjY2s)

It seems the most you can probably, really do is stick with sound design principles when designing your circuit and PCB and then work with a testing house to fix anything that went wrong.  Here are some google searches that can get you started [link1](https://www.google.com/search?q=emc%20tips) & [link2](https://www.google.com/search?q=emc%20black%20magic)